# Css :When i click in one element two was clicked

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I have a attribute It has width and my icon behind a attribute
I want click in icon but icon and a the two was clicked

what I get:

[image]

```
<div class="mob-menu-logo-holder">
 <a href="http://localhost/site1" class="headertext">
 <img class="mob-standard-logo" src="http://localhost/site1/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/logo_by_me-1.png" alt=" Logo Header Menu">
 <img class="icon_search" src="http://localhost/site1/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/icon_search.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to share your code so that we can look efficiently at what happens. Images are useless!

Comment: ok done ,i shate it now

Comment: Would you mind posting CSS too? You might try creating a jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide z-index for the image you want to click that will solve your problem

Comment: i try it and i have the same problem

Comment: Both the image are under the <a>  please provide the image under that you want to click

Comment: the same problem

Comment: create a fiddle for me then i will do it for you

Answer (score 0):

Both are within the same `<a> .. </a>` element. If you want to separate them use several of them separate:

```
<div class="mob-menu-logo-holder">
 <a href="http://localhost/commentairecompose" class="headertext">
 <img class="mob-standard-logo" src="http://localhost/site1/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/logo_by_me-1.png" alt=" Logo Header Menu">
</a>
 <a href="http://localhost/perhapsdifferentURI" class="headertext">
 <img class="icon_search" src="http://localhost/commentairecompose/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/icon_search.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: also i try this and i have the same problem

Comment: In that case, we would need to see your CSS.